# How can I find the elements of the X matrix in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

How can I find the elements of the X matrix, when I have the product of X (transpost) versus X.   (non-hermitian matrix)   in Matlab?

```
X'*X = [ 10+2*i  2+3*i  90+5*i ; 2+36*i 56-3*i 52+37*i  ; 8+13*i   20+13*i  20-9*i ]
```

Comment: Try http://math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

## Option #1 - `fsolve`

Use [fsolve](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html)- see [example 2](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html).

## Option #2 - `solve`

1. You have `n^2` variables `{a_ij} [i,j = 0,...,n]` each variable
   corresponds to a matrix entery.
2. for each one of the variable in `A'*A` define an eqution and solve the `n^2` equations. e.g. `A11^2 +A12*A21 +A13*A31 = 10+2*i`. using symbolic variable and [solve function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html)

---

```
>> s = solve(a^2+3 ==5, u+v+a ==32, a*u==1)

s = 

    a: [2x1 sym]
    u: [2x1 sym]
    v: [2x1 sym]

>> s.a

ans =

  2^(1/2)
 -2^(1/2)

>> s.v

ans =

 32 - (3*2^(1/2))/2
 (3*2^(1/2))/2 + 32

>> s.u

ans =

  2^(1/2)/2
 -2^(1/2)/2
```